# Recording audio from user on android chrome dosent play and gives empty blob in react.js

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am attempting to record audio samples from user on a PWA app. This application runs great on my Mac with the blobs being full in data. There is no problem in running the audio on the Mac. When running the PWA on my phone, blobs have 0 size, and nothing happens when running the audio.

React.js is used for the PWA. Before updating my chrome to the latest version(78.0.1304.108) the recording consisted of no problems. After the upgrade, attempts to find a solution failed. Phones with older versions work.
The following packs and JavaScript libraries were used (React-Mic,@cleandersonlobo/react-mic,React-Audio-Recorder),(getUserMedia,MediaRecorder)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved this issue, it turns out I used all audio inputs stream that chrome allows and because chrome dosent display an error regarding this it was hard to find it, so all I did was just redirecting the input streams better.